# Obtener una imagen completa en base de datos oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, substr

Hola a todos estoy tratando de obtener una imagen de una tabla en la base de datos oracle, dicha imagen se guarda en un campo de tipo blob. Ese dato que esta binarizado tengo que convertirlo a base64 para lo cual estoy usando la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(SAMDT_ARCHIVOANALITO.CONTENIDO,1400,1))) contenido
FROM SAMDT_ARCHIVOANALITO 
WHERE SAMDT_ARCHIVOANALITO.SAMDT_ANALITOLBC_ID = 22;
```

Si bien esta funcionando y me convierte el binario en base64 solo me muestra una parte de la imagen no me muestra la imagen completa según he estado viendo la función `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` solo trae una parte de los datos, pero yo necesito la imagen completa. ¿Que otra función puedo usar que me obtenga la imagen completa?.
El fin de esto es poder mostrar las imágenes que tengo guardadas en la base de datos en un campo tipo blob en un carrusel de imágenes.

Comment: Cuando habla de "imagen" se refiere a por ejemplo una foto?

Comment: Muchos lenguajes utilizan librerías que definen el tipo blob. En estos casos no tendrías que realizar ninguna conversión a varchar2 porque es aquí donde pierdes parte de las imágenes. ¿Con qué lenguaje lo lees?